# How to represent lists of complex numbers on a graph?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How to represent lists of complex numbers on a graph.

```
\[Phi][k_, x_] = G E^(-I k x) + F E^(I k x);
data = Table[
   Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][j, X[[i]]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}], {j, 0, 
    Ny}];
ComplexListPlot[data, , PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please provide definitions for `Nx`, `Ny`, `F`, `G`, `X`. Thanks.

Comment: ``` xM = 10; 
Ny = 5;
Nx = 512;
dx = 2 xM / Nx; 
X = Table[-xM + i * dx, {i, 1, Nx}];
G = 3;
F = 2; ```

Comment: You have six sets of numbers due to `Ny` running from `0` to `5`. Try this: `ComplexListPlot[Complex @@@ data[[1]]]` and change the number from `1` to `6`. You can put these on one plot, but its reduces to a cloud of dots. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

`ComplexListPlot` is for complex numbers x+iy.  You're generating the set {X[[i]], Abs[[Phi][j, X[[i]]]]^2} which is a set of real numbers.  Use `ListPlot` to plot sets of reals.  Since `data` has six sets of lists, can plot each set separately with `data[[setIndex]]` syntax.  I added a `Manipulate` to cycle through them with the points joinded into curves (removed `PlotLegends`).  Edit the code as you wish:

```
G = 3;
F = 2;
xM = 10;
Ny = 5;
Nx = 512;
dx = 2 xM/Nx;
X = Table[-xM + i dx, {i, 1, Nx}];
\[Phi][k_, x_] = G E^(-I k x) + F E^(I k x);
data = Table[
   Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][j, X[[i]]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}], {j, 0, 
    Ny}];
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data[[setIndex]], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.007]}, 
  Joined -> True],
 {{setIndex, 1}, 1, Length@data, 1}
 ]
```